# CollectionView SizeForItemAt based on Cell Class?

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

Is it possible to include sizeForItemAt code to be dynamic based on cell class? I have a collectionView with a lot of rows with different types of cells, but not in any specific pattern (it would be difficult to type 'if index path.row == 29' and so forth for each cell).

I've tried variations of the below code, but it always returns the default value (else). The code snippet here has 3 types of cells (GroupCell, MatchingButtonsCell, and MatchingEventCell).

Can I make size dynamic based on Cell Class?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    if let cell = self.masterCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? GroupCell {
        let cellHeight: CGFloat = (self.view.bounds.height * 0.55)
        let cellWidth: CGFloat = self.masterCollectionView.frame.width
        return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight)
    } else if let cell = self.masterCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? MatchingButtonsCell {
        let cellHeight: CGFloat = 60
        let cellWidth: CGFloat = self.masterCollectionView.frame.width
        return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight)
    } else if let cell = self.masterCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? MatchingEventCell {
        let cellHeight: CGFloat = 500
        let cellWidth: CGFloat = self.masterCollectionView.frame.width
        return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight)
    } else {
        let cellHeight: CGFloat = 10
        let cellWidth: CGFloat = self.masterCollectionView.frame.width
        return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight)
    }

}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

> Can I make size dynamic based on Cell Class?

Basically no. The problem is that you are assuming at the time that `sizeForItemAt` is called, there *are* "cells" where the items go. But that is not necessarily the case. For all you know, `sizeForItemAt` is called before there are *any* "cells", when the collection view is still planning its layout.

That is why you are not given a cell in the call. You are given an *index path*. And that should be all you need. You need to be able to give the answer based on the *index path*, not on something about the "cell."

And that should be easy. After all, presumably you are *setting* the cell class in your implementation of `cellForItemAt` — and you must be doing this based on the index path, because that is all the information you have. Well, if you can do it based on the index path there, do it based on the index path here.

Comment: Ok, got it... Yes, I can do it based on index path, but I was just wondering if there was an easier alternative. While developing, we keep changing where we want to place the cells and it would be nice to just set a size for a cell type! Anyway, thanks for the response.

Comment: If you think there needs to be "as easier alternative", this merely shows there is something wrong with your method architecture. Someone, somewhere, must know what kind of cell goes into each index path. You need to _abstract_ that knowledge into a method that _both_ `cellForRowAt` and `sizeForItemAt` can call. _You_ write a method called `cellTypeForIndexPath` and now the job for both the other methods is simple. If you "change where we want to place the cells" you just change that one method.